# Android - WebView is blank after screen lock

Tags: android, webview

I've got a Problem with the WebView. Basically I have a WebView and want to display html which is located in the assets folder of my device.

If I start the Activity with the WebView it will display the content of the asset file, but if I lock the screen (short-press the power button) and return to the app the content of the WebView isn't displayed. The really strange part ist, that the WebView will display the content once I click on something in the Activity.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem with Webviews?

---

Code:

In the onResume method of my Activity I load the data into the WebView

```java
webView.loadUrl( webViewUrl );
```

```xml
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/nameWrapper"
    android:layout_above="@id/buttonWrapper">

    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use Scrollview just work with Webview only , well this has nothing to do with your issue here. But to get an answer you have to show the code of your Activity class

Comment: @prateek Thanks for the fadt answer :) - I cannot post the full code of the activity, because there are currently over 1000 lines of code in this activity, so I'd like to know if somebody encountered a similar problem and can point me into the right direction.

Comment: I also had noticed of this issue. And i am afraid i need to put webviews on scrollviews environtments :(. Maybe because they are in the items of a listview or just because the activity lots of views and some are webviews.
The thing is that if you scroll pressing one of the webviews, gets blank, and when you release the press....it remains blank :(. But if you make a single click on it, it appears the text. At least this in a 3.0 tablet.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, except I have my WebView inside a RelativeLayout.